# Use jQuery load() with Local Files but Restrict Other Access to Those Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a survey online and am using jQuery to dynamically load each question one after the other, like the following:

```
$("#form-container").load("next_question.html");
```

My issue is that if someone were to go directly to "next_question.html", it will load in the browser, but the user will not have followed the proper course of action to access it.

I am wondering if there is any way to restrict access to the page from outside domains, but allow it to be accessed locally by the load() function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try loading each question in an iframe, and simply change the `src` attribute.

Comment: Wouldn't I still have the same issue in this case?

Comment: So you don't want to load the questions until a certain requirement? You could do this with JavaScript, just modify the `src` attribute of the iframe through JS.

Comment: No, my issue is that lets say in my main directory I have an index.html file and a page_2.html file. When they click a button on index, page_2.html is loaded into a certain container. I want this to be able to occur, but I don't want anyone to be able to go to www.website.com/page_2.html, I only want it to be accessible by being loaded dynamically.

Comment: I can't speak for all web server frameworks, but there may be a way to only allow access to page_2.HTML if the Referrer of the request is directly from your other webpage. Of course, I'm not 100% sure if this is a standard feature in web servers. Another option is having a cookie set in your home page, and only allow access to page_2.HTML with the cookie. Again, limited depending on web server.

Comment: I would use cookies but then I have to use javascript to check if they have access to the page and the source would still be available to the user.